# deformable objects on gazebo (ROS)

Tags: ros-electric

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

i see tht the nwe version is available but i wnat to know if the deformable physics is on it. and if this version can work with ros. Thnks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/1259/deformable-objects-on-gazebo-(ros)/) by [monidiaz](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/124/monidiaz/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 3 on 2013-02-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I think Bullet physics engine (which supports deformable objects) will be integrated starting March 8 with Gazebo 1.5. [Here](http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Roadmap) is the roadmap.

Cheers

---

Originally posted by [AndreiHaidu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/87/andreihaidu/) with karma: 2108 on 2013-02-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) on 2013-02-07**:
It's also our goal to always support ROS.